# `ngModel` not working properly when bind to an input tag in ngFor, It loose focus when i start typing

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple object of an Recipe that I want to represent here.

```
name:One,
category: Veg,
ingredient:[
"This is Ingredient 1",
"This is Ingredient 2"
]
```

So My component code look like this. I used `ngFor` to get data and bind it to the input tag.

```
      <div *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients; let i = index;" class="input-group each-step">
        <span class="input-group-prepend" id="basic-addon1">
          <span class="input-group-text">{{i+1}}</span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="recipe.ingredients[i]" name="ingredient{{i}}">
      </div>
```

So I was able to bind data but there are two major problem. I feel like they related ones.

1. The name attribute that I wanted to represent using `name="ingredient{{i}}"` is not showing up.
2. Whenever I start writing it loose focus, as you can see in the Gif below.

[image]

How to resolve this issue, If i don't want to use ReactiveForms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - 2 Way Binding with NgModel in NgFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314732/angular-2-2-way-binding-with-ngmodel-in-ngfor)

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer to the duplicate question. Contrary to what one of the comments says, `trackBy` does matter: it keeps the focus in the control. As for the `name`, it probably does not show up because you set only the property, not the attribute (that should not be a problem).

Comment: No, Didn't work. Focus still goes away.

Comment: Nothing in the error log?

Comment: Nope not at all :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngModel` will not work with variables. `recipe` in *`ngFor` needs to be an array of valid JSON, so it can iterate. `ngModel` not being correctly bound, it cannot update the model so it moves the focus. It should have shown something in error log though.

To make it work in ngFor iterate over an array with the length of recipe.ingredients.

```
<div *ngFor="let ingredient of [1,2]; let i = index" class="input-group each-step">
    <span class="input-group-prepend" id="basic-addon1">
     <span class="input-group-text">{{i+1}}</span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" #input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="recipes[0].ingredient[i]"> 

</div>
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qydie3)

If the number of `ingredient` elements is not 2 then create an array for iteration purposes:

Typescript:

```
  iterator = [];

  constructor() {
    this.recipes.forEach(item => item.ingredient.map(item =>
      this.iterator.push(item)));
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let ingredient of iterator; let i = index" class="input-group each-step">

...
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6e7far)**

Comment: The ingredients is a simple array and that how it is stored in db as well. No point of changing structure because then using Two way data binding will be pointless

Comment: Then it's not **Two Way Binding**. Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6e7far

Comment: ngFor iterates on whatever you wish but [(ngmodel)] should by on the object in order to make the twoway-binding. This is the cas here. I added interpolations to prove.

Comment: It did work but is it a hack ? Seems like not that efficient. What will be the conventional use of it ?

Comment: Which part is a hack? What you mean by efficient? It's the right way of doing. if your data is 'crooked' you need to arrange it to angular way. Your data is not valid json

Comment: That's an object provided by firebase actually. It's like that only :(

Comment: If you wish to keep ngModel, this the way to go. Otherwise you skip ngModel and manage with input or change. Hope this helped you

Comment: Would you consider upvoting ?