# Binding [(ng-Model)] value from a JSON

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-forms

I'm creating a dynamic form according to input type from a JSON , but i can't bind value of ng-Model from loop

```
<form #myForm='ngForm' (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">

   <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="formssdata">

     <ion-item *ngIf='item.inputType == "text"'>
          <ion-label  floating>{{item.label}}</ion-label>   
<ion-input type="text" required  [(ngModel)]= "{{item.key}}" name="{{item.key}}"></ion-input>    
      </ion-item>

</ng-template>

</form>
```

the binding "name" on input field is successful but binding {{item.key}} on Ng-model got error

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40315703/3843967. As I understand, you should bind formssdata with index not directly with item. Hope this helps.

Comment: As based from above link , what the syntax ?  [(ngModel)]="formsdata[index]"  or  [(ngModel)]="toDos[index].key" ......my key is a string

Comment: index can be string too.

Answer (score 0):

when using banana brackets, [()] like with ngModel, you don't need curly braces.  try this:

```
<ion-input type="text" required  [(ngModel)]= "item.key" name="{{item.key}}"></ion-input>
```