# How to *ngFor over set of ngModel bindable properties

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to use `*ngFor` for a set of identical inputs save for the property the input should bind to.

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let prop of [ID, Name, Nickname]">
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="prop.key" #propInput [(ngModel)]="prop">
    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix mat-icon-button *ngIf="propInput.value" (click)="prop='';">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-form-field>

 <!-- bind test -->
<input matInput type="text" placeholder="Name Test" #propInput [(ngModel)]="Name">
```

`prop.key` does not work, but that is a separate question.

Here is the tethered component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EntitySrcService } from '../entity-src.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-entity-table',
  templateUrl: './entity-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./entity-table.component.less']
})

export class EntityTableComponent {

  constructor(
    private entitySrc: EntitySrcService
    ) {}

  public get ID(): string {
    return this.entitySrc.id;
  }

  public set ID(value: String) {
    this.entitySrc.id = value;
  }

  public get Name(): string {
    return this.entitySrc.name;
  }

  public set Name(value: String) {
    this.entitySrc.name = value;
  }

  public get Nickname(): string {
    return this.entitySrc.altName;
  }

  public set Nickname(value: String) {
    this.entitySrc.altName = value;
  }

}
```

For the most part this seems to work as expected, but it seems the `[(ngModel)]` bind is only reading the property and not writing to it. So for example, if I update the bind test input, the Name field in the `ngFor` loop updates to match, but updating the one in the `ngFor` loop does not update the one in the test.

I'm using `get/set` properties in the component to proxy to the actually storage location, but my understanding is that a `get/set` property should act the same as a normal property (and using a normal property has the same one way bind behavior).

So how do I properly iterate over a set of properties that I want to bind to?

Comment: can you post your json object structure, if possible create a stackblitz

Comment: What is the stored data in `ID`, `Name` and `Nickname` variables..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access key and value of object using \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Comment: your approach is weird here.  Just make a component and put it on the page 3 times.

Comment: post your component code. It'll probably help a lot

Comment: A possible workaround is to use a set of property names, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ze2gqb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: @ConnorsFan can you make that an answer? That is almost exactly what I want. I feel there should be a better way to iterate over ngModel bindable properties for more complex cases, but for now at least the `this[prop]` method works.

Comment: @Barkha I don't need key-value pairs, I want to iterate over a set of ngModel bindable properties. The fact that what I have half works implies there should be a way to properly do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `[ID, Name, Nickname]` contains the values of the three properties, not their references. The two-way binding will modify the array items instead of the original properties (for that to work, you must refer to the items by their index and track the array by index, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40315703/1009922)).

To achieve two-way binding of the component properties, you could use an array of property names, and refer to each property with `this[prop]`:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let prop of ['ID', 'Name', 'Nickname']">
  <input [(ngModel)]="this[prop]" ... >
  ...
</mat-form-field>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ze2gqb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that `[ID, Name, Nickname]` are value types. In this case `*ngFor` just uses their values without binding to the original variables.
If you still need binding, you should consider transforming them to reference types.

For example you could put them into the object, like person or options and iterate object properties using `KeyValuePipe`:
[How to iterate object keys using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-keys-using-ngfor)

```
options: {[key: number]: string} = {ID: '1', Name: 'bar', Nickname: 'foo'};

<div *ngFor="let item of options | keyvalue">
```

Comment: item in this example isn't bindable to `[(ngModel)]`.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 6.1 the KeyValuePipe was introduced which allows you to iterate object properties:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: I don't need key-value pairs. I'm specifically looking to use ngFor over a set a properties to be bound to ngModel.