# ngModel two way databinding does not bind correctly inside a *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular2-ngmodel

I have the following html inside a ngForm:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-flex" *ngFor="let customerRole of customerRoles; let i = index">
    <div class="role-name">
      <label for="roleName">Rolename{{i + 1}}</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='role-name' id="roleName" [(ngModel)]="customerRole.name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="hourly-wage"> // can ignore this div, works similary as role-name above
      <label for="hourlyWage">Hourly wage</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name='hourlyWage' id="hourlyWage"
               [(ngModel)]="customerRole.hourlyWage"/>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text ignore-radius">€</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" id="deleteRole" (click)="deleteRole(customerRole)" ngbTooltip="Delete role">
      <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a class="add-role-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-plus" (click)="addRole()" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Add role"></i>
    </a>
    <label *ngIf="customerRoles.length === 0; else addMoreRoles">Add role</label>
    <ng-template #addMoreRoles>
      <label>Add another role</label>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `addRole()` method looks like this:

```
    addRole() {
    this.customerRoles.push(createInitialRole());
  }
```

customerRoles is just an array containing roles.

And thats how it looks:

[image]

So theres always a new role, containing a rolename and a hourlyWage, getting added in everytime i press the "add another role" button.
I have problems with the ngModel binding, everytime i add another role, every inputs value changes to the value of the last element added to the customerRoles array for some reason.

So if i added another role to the image above, it would look like this:

[image]

Every inputs value in the view changes to the value of the last role added, which in this case contains an empty name and an empty hourly wage. Role 1 and 2 bind to the value of Role 3 after its added in for some reason. The customerRoles array contains the correct elements. It for example still contains the junior softwaredeveloper role at the 0th index. Why does it suddenly display the latest added value to the array instead of the value its binded to? If i use

```
value="{{customerRole.name}}"
(input)="customerRole.name= $event.target.value"
```

instead of

```
[(ngModel)]="customerRole.name"
```

everything works as expected, but thats a workaround i dont want to take.

Edit:

Just for testing purposes, if i display `customerRole.name` in the label above the input field like this

```
<label for="roleName">{{customerRole.name}}</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name='role-name' id="roleName" [(ngModel)]="customerRole.name"/>
```

the label keeps showing the correct value while the input field, switches to the value of the last element added like previously mentioned.

Comment: Move your Role name input & Hourly wage & delete button to child component and pass  customerRole as @Input() customerRole: Role and pass delete callback if you need like  @Input() onDelete: Function. Now you can add elements to your array.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314732/angular-2-2-way-binding-with-ngmodel-in-ngfor?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML generated by the ngFor will be incorrect as all the roleName inputs have the same `name` and `id`. I think this might cause the `ngFor` to misbehave.

due to this part `... name='role-name' id="roleName" ...` (and the same for the other ones)

Remove the names and ids (or make them unique per iteration) and all should work again

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I had to make them unique, for example `id="roleName{{index}}"`.