# Angular Edit all values on a table

Tags: angular

I have an array that I'm showing on a table, but I need to edit all the values in one column of that table. My code is like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let line of invoice.lines; let index = index">
    <td>
        {{line.quantity}}
    </td>
    <td style="width: 35%">
        {{line.productName}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="order_price"
        id="field_order_price" [(ngModel)]="line.price"/>
    </td>
...
</tr>
```

The thing is that the `input` has the same value in all the rows (which is the last one in the array). I tried printing the value of `line.price` next to the `input` to be sure that the I'm getting the right values and this is what I get:

[image: correct value + wrong values]

What am I missing?

UPDATE 1: changed by suggstions hasn't worked :(

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="order_price" (click)="onOrderPriceChange(index)" id="field_order_price1_{{index}}" [(ngModel)]="invoice.lines[index].price"/>
```

Angular:

```
trackByIndex(index: number, line: IInvoiceLine): any {
    return line.id;
  }
```

Comment: Seems to be common to experience issues with `[(ngModel)]` within an `*ngFor` directive. I've not come across this yet myself, but maybe take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40315703/12431728

Comment: I added `trackBy` but it hasn't change the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each input should have a unique ID attribute. Let me know if you have some queries.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let line of invoice.lines; let index = index">
  <td>
    {{line.quantity}}
  </td>
  <td style="width: 35%">
    {{line.productName}}
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="{{'order_price_' + index}}" id="{{'field_order_price_' + index}}" [(ngModel)]="invoice.lines[index].price" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

> Hope this helps :)

Comment: _almost_ there, I still see the '12' as value, but while inspecting I can see the correct value as 'ng-reflect-model="16.95"' why could that be?

Comment: just wanting to know have you updated the `Id` & `[(ngModel)]` as shown in the code? apparently having same ids for multiple attributes might lead to this

Comment: @Alejandro I have updated the answer, turns out `name` needs to be unique as well. Give it a shot

Comment: thank you. That did it, both id and name must be unique

Comment: @Ayyub, it's not necesary an unique "id", really it's not necesary use "id". The key is, obviously, give different variable to [(ngModel)]

Comment: actually no, the variable for ngModel is the same as we are talking about an array so the field's name remains unchanged

Answer (score 2):

You need to give a UNIQUE ID for each input. You can also use the below code to resolve your concern.

```
<tr *ngFor="let line of invoice.lines; let index = index">
  <td>
      {{line.quantity}}
  </td>
  <td style="width: 35%">
      {{line.productName}}
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" [id]="'field_order_price' + index" [(ngModel)]="line[index]" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps!
Thank you.

Comment: Idem comentary about "id" that before answers

Comment: noup, your comment doesn't apply to this answer. This answer is also correct.