# Angular binding object with array from component to view with ngModels

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I tried to bind my model on my view, but I have a problem when I submit my form : I don't have an array, but many property.

component :

```
export class QuizFormAddQuestionComponent implements OnInit {
    public question: Question;

    constructor() {
        this.question = new Question();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.question.setModel({ question: 'test' });
        this.question.setAnswers(3);
    }

    createQuestion(form) {
        console.log(form.value);
    }

}
```

my template :

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">

        <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createQuestion(form)" class="mt-4">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label for="question" class="col-form-label">Question</label>
                    <input type="text"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="question"
                           placeholder="Enter your question..."
                           name="question"
                           [ngModel]="question.question"
                           required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" *ngFor="let answer of question.answers; let i = index;">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input"
                                   type="checkbox"
                                   id="answer-value-{{i}}"
                                   [ngModel]="question.answers[i].value"
                                   name="answers[{{i}}].value">
                            Answer {{ i }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="answer-text-{{i}}"
                           [ngModel]=question.answers[i].text
                           name="answers[{{i}}].text">
                           {{ answer.getManipulateObjet() }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-froup col-md-12 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add question</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

question.ts (model)

```
import { Answer } from "./answer";

export class Question {

    constructor(private question: string          = '',
                private answers: any[]            = [],
                private more_informations: string = '',
                private difficulty: number        = 0,) {
    }

    setModel(obj) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }

    addAnswer() {
        let new_answer = new Answer();

        new_answer.setModel({ text: 'test', value: false });

        this.answers.push(new_answer);
    }

    setAnswers(number_answers) {
        for (let i = 0; i < number_answers; i++) {
            this.addAnswer();
        }

        console.log(this);
    }

}
```

answer.ts (model)

```
export class Answer {

    constructor(private text: string  = '',
                private value: boolean = false,) {
    }

    setModel(obj) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }

    getManipulateObjet() {
      return '=== call getManipulateObjet() for example : return more information after manipulating object, count value properties, concat, etc... ===';
    }

    getCount() {
      // ....
    }

    getInspectMyObject() {
      // ...
    }
}
```

initial object :

[image]

console after submit :

[image]

**After the submit I would like the same things as the initial object (same structure with the data updated), the same data structure before and after submit**

I tried this on in my view, but it doesn't work :

```
<div class="form-group row" *ngFor="let answer of question.answers; let i = index;">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input"
                       type="checkbox"
                       id="answer-value-{{i}}"
                       [ngModel]="answer.value"
                       name="answer[{{i}}].value">
                Answer {{ i }}
            </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               id="answer-text-{{i}}"
               [ngModel]=answer.text
               name="answer[{{i}}].text">
               {{ answer.getManipulateObjet() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I transform in the *ngFor **[ngModel]=question.answers[i].text** by **[ngModel]="answer.text"**, but I have the same problem...

I tried many things from differents posts : [Angular 2 form with array of object inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207746/angular-2-form-with-array-of-object-inputs), [Angular 2 - 2 Way Binding with NgModel in NgFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314732/angular-2-2-way-binding-with-ngmodel-in-ngfor)

But always many properties and no array

**I would like to do this without reactive form, only template driven**

> Demo:

https://angular-by7uv1.stackblitz.io/

I would like to use different function from my object 'answer', for example : answer.getInformation(), getCount(), getInspectMyObject() etc.. to iterate on my object only, in my view. This function is provided by my model 'Answer' to have a clean code in my view. I would like use many functions from my model in the *ngFor. If I use the reactive form, I can't use different function from my model because the "link" between my parent object and my childs is broken.

> SOLVED

https://fom-by-template-driven.stackblitz.io

Comment: from your template, add code for your `Add Question` button

Comment: @Faisal I updated my post

Comment: im not entirely sure what the problem is but if you arent getting data, you need to add a standalone property to each input

Comment: @mast3rd3mon After the submit I would like the same things as the initial object (same structure with the data updated)

Comment: you mean you want the data to reset? or you want the same data structure?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon the same data structure

Comment: not too sure as i dont use forms like that, i read the data myself so i know i will always have the same structure

Comment: what is the problem you are facing can you explain a bit , the data is coming as objects , and you want it as array of objects on submit is that so ?

Comment: @RahulSingh After the submit I would like the same things as the initial object (same structure with the data updated), the same data structure before and after submit

Comment: same data structure means , you have a form it will follow the same structure @JérémieChazelle

Comment: @RahulSingh This is the problem. I can not recreate the same structure with my form

Comment: @JérémieChazelle can you provide the stackblitz code base link ?

Comment: @RahulSingh sure https://stackblitz.io/edit/angular-by7uv1

Comment: @JérémieChazelle how is the structure you are looking at can you just give a small gist on the structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153753/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-jeremie-chazelle).

Comment: @JérémieChazelle still need help in this?

Comment: @Rajez it's ok thx !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, whatever the `input` name specified, it will be considered as just text. Should not reference any `Object` or `Array`.But with slight modifications, there is a chance to obtain the same data structure with updated data.

All elements are binded in one way, so make it two way binding. So whenever `input` value changes, The binded `element` value updates.

```
 [(ngModel)]="question.question"
```

Use `template driven form` for validation

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createQuestion()" class="mt-4">
...
<button [disabled]="!form.valid"
```

Now the values are validated & updated in the variable `question`.There is no need to get the value from form, use the updated object `question` to create question.

```
createQuestion() {
        console.log(this.question);
    }
```

[View the results in worked out App](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lrqfdk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({

  selector: 'form-component',

  template: `

    <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <div formArrayName="inputs" *ngFor="let control of formArray;     let i = index;">
        <input placheholder="Name please" formControlName="{{i}}"/>
      </div>
    </form>

    <button (click)="addInput()">Add input</button>

  `
})

export class FormComponent implements OnInit{

  formGroup: FormGroup;


  contructor() {
  }


  ngOnInit(){

    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      inputs: new FormArray([
        new FormControl("Hello"),
        new FormControl("World"),
      ]);
    });
  }

  get formArray() {

    return this.formGroup.get('inputs').controls
  }


  addInput(){

    this.formArray.push(new FormControl("New Input"));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i see that you are using `[ngModel]` in you html template. this will only bind the input to bind the output as well you need to use `[(ngModel)]`. this is the regular way of using `ngModel`. i find one more wrong in your code that    `name="answer[{{i}}].value"`here name is value should be constant, you are giving it as variable the correct way of writing it is `name="{{answer[i].value}}"`

[image]

Comment: When I modified with your modifications I have many errors, If you want to try it : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-by7uv1

Comment: hi i modified the code what i said in the answer it worked fine this is the code i added in the html.

Comment: i am not able add the html code here it says to long. How can i share the code to you

Comment: You can Fork my project on stackbiltz and share the link in your post

Comment: Sure : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:31)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (

Comment: just a try make this change in the question model

  addAnswer() {
        this.answers.push(new Answer());
        this.answers['text']='test';
        this.answers['value']=false;
    }

Comment: please change in you project on stackblitz and share it or updated your post

Comment: Same error, may be save your project to apply your modification ?

Comment: https://angular-dhuwaf.stackblitz.io. i have saved this. and working fine

Comment: open your console on stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhuwaf, many errors

Answer (score 0):

The following scenario is **not possible using the current Angular Template driven form**.
There is a issue raised to the Angular Team [**LINK**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9615).

Its requires a lot of rework as the template driven forms uses ngModel . Angular Forms are moving towards reactive approach and in the near feature i dont see this feature being added to it.

Please use Reactive forms for this `formArrayName` will be sufficient to help get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
academicYearTerms: [{
    term_name: {
        type: String,
        default: " "
    },
    term_end: {
        type: Date,
    },
    term_start: {
        type: Date,
    },
}]
```

declare in node js

```
adminpageform = new FormGroup({
    start_date: new FormControl(''),
    end_date: new FormControl(''),
    acadyr_shortcode: new FormControl(''),
    no_terms: new FormControl(''),
    term_name: new FormControl(''),
    term_end: new FormControl(''),
    term_start: new FormControl(''),
    TermsId: new FormControl('')
});
```

declare in ts 
how to store in array of object value in form control